# What does "Sublicense" mean?

Tags: licensing

In the Freepik license for vectors it says "You are not allowed to: Sub-license, resell or rent it." What does "Sublicense" mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question. Sub-licensing means to license to a third party though.

Answer (score 2):

In very short terms, it means *you* can't grant anyone else permission to do anything with the file.